# Getting error java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transactional EntityManager available

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I am getting this error even when I have Tagged it with @Transactional:

```
@Service
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@Transactional
Public class Test{
 
   
   protected void getAAA() {
      List<X> list = getxxx();
   }
   
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional
   public List getxxx(){
   
     Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        NativeQuery query = session.createNativeQuery("select * from table");
        
        }
}
```

Error:Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transactional EntityManager available

Comment: can you add  your @Configuration for the database ?

Comment: I did put @Configuration on the Test class but still getting same error.

Comment: Sorry, I mean can you add in the post

Comment: Using Oracle db., more code from XXX: 
             SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
             Transactional
             public List getxxx(){
   
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    NativeQuery query = session.createNativeQuery("select * from table");
    query.addScalar().setTransformer(SomeDTO.class)
            }     
  
   Data //Annotation
   JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY) //Annotation
   NoArgsConstructor //Annotation
   public class SomeDTO{
   }